# Uploaded image via django admin not found, altough URL seems correct

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-media

as Django newby I am strugling to get an image on screen. After reading tons of questions and answers to problems alike, I am only more puzzled, because it looks like I coded the necesary, but I get an 404 error when clicking on an image link in the admin page or trying to show an image in a template. While the two seem related I will stick to the admin site.

This is what I am seeing in the admin site:

[image: Image in admin site]

To me it looks correct from what I have seen/read.

But when I click the link I get a 404 error:

[image: Error message when clicking image link]

Altough the media URL seems to work, because the images/Presentation_....jpg is now prefixed by http://.../media/

The image is in the following directory:

[image: directory]

Where C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\website_andalucia is my BASE_DIR (when I print it from settings.py)

The necesary code looks like this:

My_project/catalog/settings.py

```
DEBUG = True
...
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
# Path where media is stored
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
print("base dir:", BASE_DIR)
print("media root:", MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My_project/my_project/models.py (see the remark_image)

```
class remark(models.Model):
    # Fields
    activity = models.ForeignKey(activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    remark_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    remark_desc = models.TextField(help_text='Enter your remark(s) here')
    remark_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

My_project/catalog/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
path('activities/', views.activitiesView.as_view(), name='activities'),
path('activity/<int:pk>', views.activityDetailView.as_view(), name='activity-detail'),
path('my_activities/', views.userActivitiesView.as_view(), name='my_activities'),
path('add_activity/', views.add_activity, name='add_activity'),
path('activity/<int:pk>/add_remark/', views.add_remark, name='add_remark'),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My_project/my_project/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='catalog/', permanent=True)),
path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Why do I get the 404 error message instead of the image?

PS I am on Windows 10, using PyCharm, Python 3.11.0 and a venv with Django 4.1.5

Comment: media files url pattern does not seem to be included into global urlpatterns. However static url pattern is included (shown on error screenshot). Check all urls.py, make sure DEBUG = true

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for your thoughts, `DEBUG = True` is my settings.py. When printing my urlpatterns from my urls.py they look like: [<URLPattern '' [name='index']>, ...,  <URLPattern '^media/(?P<path>.*)$'>, does that look good?

Comment: Show other urls.py files including all operations with `urlpatterns`

Comment: I get the point! I need to add `if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to my urls.py in my_project/my_project as well! This did the job for the admin page, thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all urlpatterns from all the secondary urls.py files into final, main `urlpatterns` set in the main project `urls.py` file.

Example from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/urls/#path):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("index/", views.index, name="main-view"),
    path("bio/<username>/", views.bio, name="bio"),
    path("articles/<slug:title>/", views.article, name="article-detail"),
    path("articles/<slug:title>/<int:section>/", views.section, name="article-section"),
    path("blog/", include("blog.urls")), ### <<<--- here /blog/urls.py is included
    ...,
]
```

in case of `my_project/app/urls.py` it will be `path("", include("app.urls"))` in the `my_project/urls.py`

upd

this include

`path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),`

means that all the urls from `catalog/urls.py` are supposed to be prefixed by `catalog/`. That's why Django is unable to map `/media/...` to any urlpattern - there is no such url pattern registered, there is only `/catalog/media/...` url pattern.

I guess the rest of `catalog` app urls are really supposed to be under `/catalog/` URL, but *media* files and media files url pattern are global things, common to the whole project thus it is better to *move* (not copy) media url pattern to the place where static files url pattern is defined:

My_project/my_project/urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: It seemed to be included: `urlpatterns = [..., path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='catalog/', permanent=True)), path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')), ...,
]`, but only adding `urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` helps at this moment. Catalog is the name of my app..

Comment: Pieces of code are too small and whole picture is not clear, not possible to connect things together. If they were correctly included then explicit `+=` would have no effect.

Comment: In the question I added the remaining lines to My_project/catalog/urls.py and I added My_project/my_project/urls.py (which does work without the added MEDIA pattern). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, works. Thank you for your clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to write this sentence `{% load static %}` in your html at the first line?